# SvelteKit deployment on Vercel using Git repo

Tags: github, dns, vercel, sveltekit

There is an issue coming up that I don't know the resolution for:

```
s.at is not a function. (In 's.at(-1)', 's.at' is undefined)
```

[image]

Initially, I thought that was the git repo problem. However, it still popped up after resetting everything and clearing the commit history. The git commit works fine, but whenever I add a new project on the Vercel dashboard, it results in a mentioned build error.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

I have also noticed a weird feature that also appears on my other projects if I click on deployment domains rather than on normal ones.